# Nginx - reverse proxy and sub directory

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse

I would like to make a reverse proxy, which serves a HTTP request, forwards it to one of servers, and then provides a response from that server to client.

For example, client makes the following request: nginxproxy/server1 The result from server is shown to the client. If client clicks on any link (they are relative), the request will be made to: nginxproxy/anylink, but, I would need this link to be nginxproxy/server1/anylink

Is it possible to achieve this with Nginx? Current configuration is very simple, and looks like this:

```html
  location /server1/ {
    proxy_pass http://server1/;
    proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  }
```

Comment: This could depend on your application server as well.  For example, some app servers requires that the prefix path (ie. /server1) is configured as well.

Answer (score 0):

On application server I have added alias.url configuration to 'server1' folder and it works.